# why my file permission being changed after pull from git repository

Tags: git, file-permissions

I have been came across this problem over and over again. I have a git repository set up on my remote server and all the files are set to 644 and folders are set to 755. However, every time after i pulling from git repository(i'm using bitbucket), i noticed the permission of the file which i modified was changed into 664 which results a Internal server Error. For example, I changed the index.php, and it occurs 500 when i tried to get access to it

i have to use 
`find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755` and `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644` to manually changed my files permission back to normal

Comment: What does your `umask` say? If you need new files to be `0644`, it should be saying `022`.

Comment: no, it says 0002, It's that the problem? so I need to use umask 022?

Comment: Yes, it is. `umask` is the set of permissions you _don't_ want to set on new files. Generally, on any new file by any program; nothing specific to git. If you don't want group write permission, you have to set `umask` to 022.

Comment: yes, thanks and i would try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in "[Git set create mode to 100664 when pushing new folder/files to shared repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14333611/6309)":

> git doesn't store file permissions at the level you want. Having 644 or 664 files depends purely on `umask`."

(`022` in your case, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222079/why-my-file-permission-being-changed-after-pull-from-git-repository#comment39286865_25222079) by [Jan Hudec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201725/jan-hudec)

Git only stores two permissions (`755=rwxr.xr.x`, `644=rw.r..r..`).

> git simply doesn't track permissions.
>   In fact, it refuses to. Turns out there are enough mutually-exclusive definitions of how to do it right, all of which can be whipped up with simple scripting, that the simple scripting is the right way to implement it.
>   Plus, those rules are best left per-repo, because there's repo purpose and host OS to consider.