# Getting Clear read only status on Webstorm 8

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have webstorm 8 installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I am trying to edit a file but I am getting a popup, with heading "Clear read only status", which shows file and two radio button

- Using File System
- Using version control integration

When I select Using File system and click OK, nothing happens, and it doesn't allow to select Second option.

I am using git as my dcvs.

Please guide me on how I can remove this read only status from that file.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

I had similar problem and I ran following command and my problem was resolved:

> sudo chown -R $(whoami) my-project-folder

Works on both Ubuntu & OS X

To check username use: whoami

Comment: Worked on OS X w/git + Webstorm 9

Comment: yup. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) project-folder`

Comment: This helped me too, and I had the problem in Webstorm10!

Comment: I have searched a lot at jetbrains.com but it did not give me right solution.Thanks @Raheel. FYI, I did not face this situation at windows ever. This is for only linux and Mac I faced.

Comment: or `sudo chown -R \`whoami\` <folder>`

Comment: I made an angular project as root, now i can't edit the app.component.html file in webstorm, help!

Comment: @Debadatta as it is mentioned in the answer, you;ll have to change the ownership of the project folder. `sudo chown -R `whoami` <folder>`

Comment: yeah, works... I just wanted to add what the folder is it's basically a path which can be absolute or relative. So it can be `/Users/username/Documents/automation-dashboard`

Answer (score 4):

Same answer as above but use the current user and also add the files to the current group

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER my-project-folder
```

$USER is a variable which stores your currently logged in user,at least on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

> When I select Using File system and click OK, nothing happens

Nothing *visible* happen, but you should be able to edit your file, since the file should now be in 755 mode (as opposed to 644)

More generally, [check your `umask`](http://linuxzoo.net/page/sec_umask.html): it should be 0022, which means a git clone would by default create 644 files (writable), as detailed in "[why my file permission being changed after pull from git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25225524/6309)".

> it doesn't allow to select Second option.

That may be because the sources edited in Webstorm aren't in a git repo.

Comment: Hi VonC, I am new to linux so don't know what exactly 644 and 755 mode means. However I am also looking into this

Comment: My file seems to be in 644 mode 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root                root                 1283 Aug 20 17:04 profileMenu.html

Comment: @Mozak yes, but it owned by 'root', and you are likely to launch your IDE Webstorm as your account (and not root), hance the read-only attribute. You chould chown all those files into your account (http://superuser.com/a/260939).