# Git Install Script How to enter shell command

Tags: linux, git, perl, shell, openshift

This is more of a git related question than openshift.
When I push files to the git server using git, I see that the file permissions of my perl `index.cgi` file gets changed to 700 in my openshift repo.
Hence every time I do a push, I have to log in to the server using ssh and do a `chmod a+x index.cgi` in my `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` to change it to 755.

I read in the git documentation it is possible to add a hook and I tried updating the post update script in the hooks directory with the following command

```
exec chmod a+x $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/index.cgi
```

However that does not seemed to have worked.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong ?
How can I ensure I don't have to make the `chmod` change every time I push files ?

How does one execute shell commands via the git install script (I don't know what is install script, I assume it means the hooks)

based on a below suggestion i thought i would need to add the hook to the server so i tried it but i got an error

`$ git add .git/hooks/post-update
error: Invalid path '.git/hooks/post-update'
error: unable to add .git/hooks/post-update to index`

so i tried some options using [action hooks](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_user_guide.html#action-hooks) by placing a "start" in the local .openshift/action_hooks directory.

The command there ive tried to use was 
 `exec chmod a+x register.cgi` and even `chmod a+x register.cgi`

Not much luck. Any inputs. I will be raising this as a separate q against actionhooks.

Answer (score 3):

> This is more of a git related question than openshift.

Actually, it is more related to openshift than it is to Git: [Git only records 644 and 755 permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25225524/6309).

But the destination system managing a checkout (and updating a working tree) would set the permission according to the [default **`umask`**](http://linuxzoo.net/page/sec_umask.html) (which could be in your case `077`).
Make sure the default `umask` is `022`.

Regarding the hook, check its name ('`post-update`', no extension) and permission (it must be executable, 755 would be useful)

Comment: thanks for the tip on umask. its set as 0077.making it as 022 would if i understand correctly ensure my files will have 644 permissions right ?

Comment: the hook is named post-update in my local git hooks folder. now after ure post i tried adding the hook to the git server, but i got an error. I also tried editing the hook sample in the openshift/git/app.git/hooks folder, but it did not give me permissions to write the file there as the hooks folder is owned by root.

Comment: @RonAbraham that would explain why the hook didn't execute: it is a server hook, executed by the remote repo which receives commits. And you cannot "git add" a hook: a hook is never pushed.

Comment: @RonAbraham yes, that would be a separate issue (and you can link back to this question, that you can accept)

Comment: @Just create a new question, that will be easier to answer. I'll edit it to add the link back to this one.

Comment: thans VonC heres the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609567/how-to-use-to-make-a-file-executable-on-openshift-server-after-pushing-it-via-gi)

Answer (score 1):

Bring authority in this case gitweb folder.

> gitweb/
>   drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Sep 25 12:01 .
>   drwxr-xr-x 225 root root  12288 Oct 27 20:10 ..
>   -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 251319 Sep 23 04:36 gitweb.cgi
>   lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     10 Sep 23 04:36 index.cgi -> gitweb.cgi
>   drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 25 12:01 static

Comment: nice trick. but ure post is a bit cryptic. u mean create a symbolic link of somekind ? i didnt get u.