# How to use to make a file executable on Openshift server after pushing it via git

Tags: linux, git, openshift, file-permissions

The original poser is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602640/git-install-script-how-to-enter-shell-command/26603078?noredirect=1#comment41830126_26603078).
I want to ensure my index.cgi is set to 755, even afer i push files to git.
This is not happening and the file permission , based on the umask i understand is getting set to 700.

I am unable to create the post-update script on the server , which is to be kept at openshift/hooks location, due to the set permissions.

So i tried using [action hooks](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_user_guide.html#action-hooks) to do the job.

I created a file named stop in my action hooks local folder.
Following this i pushed my index file to the server.

My index file still shows permission as 700.
How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the permissions in git.

```
 git update-index --chmod=<permissions>   <your_file>
```