# Changing the permission of file already added to git

Tags: git, ubuntu, permissions

Recently I came across permission related issue for a file in git. Actually one of my team members while committing a file didn't notice there is no write permission for group level.

Consider a file - `file.txt`. She committed and pushed the file, while the permission on her machine was - `644 (rw-r--r--)`. And when I tried to do a `git pull`, it returned with following error for that file:

```
$ git pull
error: unable to create file file.txt
```

So I did try a couple of things without success:

- First I changed the file permission on my team member machine, and pushed it again. But that didn't help.
- Then I deleted the file, and re-created it with proper permission. And then added the new file to git. Again, that didn't work.

Finally I've to resort to use `sudo`:

```
$ sudo git pull
```

And that did work. But I'm still unknown about how to fix the issue without using `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

644 and 755 are the [only tow permissions recorded by Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25225524/6309).

`sudo` should not be used usually, unless you are in a common server (accessed by multiple users) where the local repo is not created as you.

If it is your repo, try a:

```
sudo chown -R <yourUser> .
```

And see if the error persist on `git pull`.

Comment: I'm trying the re-produce the issue on my machine, creating a local and remote repo. I pushed a file with owner as `root` and `644` as permission, and pulled that on a different local repo. Suprisingly it created the file.. :( And it changed the owner to me, and permission to 664.

Comment: @RohitJain that is expected. 644 is a perfectly fine permission. The repo is a local rpeo and operation will be done as the local user which operates said local repo.

Comment: So, if I would have changed the owner of that file from my team member's machine to her user, instead of root, it would work?

Comment: @RohitJain yes, using root is generally not a good practice for a local repo owned by a user.